# Proof: If a solution of the nonhomogeneous wave equation exists, then it is unique.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, cauchy-problem

So I was going through the proof of a proposition which states that, 'If a solution of the nonhomogeneous wave equation exists, then it is unique.' It is the very first proof in the following pdf:
[The Cauchy Problem for the Nonhomogeneous Wave Equation](http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat606/lecture12.pdf)

But, on page 2 of the above pdf, I did not understand how, while differentiating $v_t(x,t)$ again, or, while finding out $v_{tt}(x,t)$, they differentiated with respect to t, but wrote $F_x(...)$ in the next step?

Can you please explain how they did that?

Comment: Looks to me like an application of the Green's theorem given on first page.

Comment: if you don't mind, can u explain in more detail how the theorem has been used to get $F_x()$??